# vtiger Web Form + changed module

Tags: vtiger

I have installed the vtiger 5.4.0 in my pc and I want create a webform to Contact Module ... How I will be able to select another module (only exists Leads) when I create a webform?

Answer (score 1):

Module : Select a module in which records should be captured. **Vtiger only supports capturing leads.**

reference: https://wiki.vtiger.com/vtiger6/index.php/Webforms